# How to validate Form only on submit in Angular Dart?

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-components, angular-dart

I am using the Angular Component library which includes *material-input*. Is there a way to disable input **auto validate** when changing or emptying the *material-input*?  Meaning that I want to only **validate** the form upon **submit**.

Plus the onSignInPressed() function is not getting triggered on submit despite that the *material-button* is of type submit.

```
    <div class="container">
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSignInPressed()" #signInForm="ngForm">
            <div>
                <material-input
                        floatingLabel type="email"
                        label="E-mail"
                        [(ngModel)]="email"
                        ngControl="email"
                        required></material-input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <material-input
                        floatingLabel type="password"
                        label="Password"
                        [(ngModel)]="password"
                        ngControl="pass"
                        required></material-input>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100">
                <material-button class="mx-0 btn-primary w-100 margin-zero" type="submit"
                                 [disabled]="!signInForm.form.valid">
                        Sign In
                </material-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a different value accessor on the material-input, however you won't be able to validate the form on submit.

With `changeUpdate`, validation will be triggered on blur or when press ENTER

```dart
<material-input changeUpdate [(ngModel)]="value"
```

[Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/angular_components/latest/material_input_material_input_default_value_accessor/MaterialInputChangeValueAccessor-class.html)

About the material-button, there is an issue on [github](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/269) with a hacky solution.

You can also try to add an hidden input

```html
<input type="submit" hidden />
```

Comment: Hello Hadrien.  How could you validate the form then? Does creating custom validators solve this?

Comment: This does not change anything to form validation and you still can create custom validator using NgForm API. Take a look at this guide https://angulardart.dev/guide/forms

Comment: Is there an attribute that takes a boolean and handles when to show the error? Thank you Hadrien!